# Small gaps between table cells

Tags: html, css

I have a table in which I would like the borders to collapse and all the cells to touch. I feel like I may be missing something obvious, but the bottom borders are not showing at all despite having height assigned to them. They instead just separate the cells from one another allowing the background color to show through (red in the example).

If I change the `border-collapse` to `separate` the borders re-appear, but the gaps remain as well as adding gaps between the columns as well.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/32o87x7L/)

Comment: Put your `border-bottom: 1px solid #212121` on the `<tr>` instead. https://jsfiddle.net/32o87x7L/1/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As is usually the case, I solved my own problem right after submitting my question. :-/

Apparently table-cells do not take too well to positioning as they cannot be consistently. Removing `position: relative;` from the `.defaultTable th, .defaultTable td` did the trick.

Comment: @dippas i will mark it in 48 hours which is the minimum if you perform a self-answer

Answer (score 0):

You are not targeting the **Table Row**, see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/32o87x7L/3/

```
.defaultTable tr{border-bottom: 2px solid blue;}
.defaultTable th,
.defaultTable td {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 9px 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  background: #eee;
  border: none;
  //border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```